# PHP Variable in mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable like this:

```
$var = "INSERT INTO `gaz_001rigdoc`(`id`) VALUES (".$variabletest.");";
```

Afterwards, I need do this:

```
$querygo = mysql_query ($var);
```

Is this possible? How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: yes it is possible... you just did it...

Comment: I try but don't work

Comment: You should not use the deprecated `mysql_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`with prepared statements

Comment: print the query and check

Comment: Add single quotes arround the value `$var = "INSERT INTO `gaz_001rigdoc`(`id`) VALUES ('".$variabletest."')";`

Comment: If the variable `$variabletest` is a string you need to use quotes around it, for numbers that should be fine as it is. Though if you are just beginning with php / mysql ~ save yourself the pain now and look into using PDO or, at the very least, mysqli

Comment: You don't need to close your double quotes to place php variables into an SQL query

`INSERT INTO gaz_001rigdoc(`id`) VALUES($variabletest);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

> $var = "INSERT INTO `gaz_001rigdoc`(`id`) VALUES
>   ('".$variabletest."')";

Comment: It work man. Thank you. I have a very long variable and i don't remember the '' between the value. Thank you again!

Comment: In that case please have a read of http://docs.php.net/security.database.sql-injection (chances are you haven't considered it yet).

Answer (score 2):

Mysql query need **' '** with every string

```
$var = "INSERT INTO `gaz_001rigdoc`(`id`) VALUES ('$variabletest')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse you could do that:

```
$variabletest = 123;

$var = "INSERT INTO `gaz_001rigdoc`(`id`) VALUES ('$variabletest')";

$querygo = mysqli_query($con, $var);
```

> Notice: `$con` is a connection made variable in mysqli.

Comment: Might have been something fancy I didn't know about ;)

Comment: @Epodax Ahh, I see what you did there ;)